# Unit test API Call with internal switch case

Tags: ios, swift, xctestcase

I am trying to unit test a class that has different modes of setup.

```
class Controller{

    enum Mode{
        case listing
        case pages(String?)
    }

    private (set) var mode : Mode = .listing
    private (set) var models = [Model]()

    init() {
        ...
    }

    init(id : String) {
        mode = .pages(id)
    }

    func fetchInfo(){

        switch mode{
           case .listing: 
               ApiManager.firstNetworkCall(){ (json, error) in ... 
                    setupModel()
               }
           case .pages(let id):
               ApiManager.secondNetworkCall(id : id){ (json, error) in ... 
                    setupModel()
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these will update the `models` array with different quantity of data.

What I have right now:

```
var controller : Controller!

override func setUpWithError() throws {

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    try super.setUpWithError()
    controller = Controller()
}

override func tearDownWithError() throws {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    controller = nil
    try super.tearDownWithError()
}

func testDefaultListingMode() throws {

    switch controller.mode{
       case .listing:
           XCTAssertTrue(true)
       default:
           XCTAssertFalse(false)
    }
}

func testAPISetup() throws {

    controller.fetchInfo()
    //now what?
}
```

This checks if the mode is correct but I am trying to go one step further and check if the correct number of items is setup depending on the mode. And want to call the `fetchInfo()` method directly from the `XCTestCase` and just validate the model count.

All the tutorials and guides I have seen just talk about faking the behaviour with a `URLSession`. But the API call is dependent on the mode that happens as an internal check inside the `fetchInfo` method and is the only method exposed to other classes. I would simply like to test the method (in case something breaks inside that method causing a bug).

How do I go about doing that? I can't figure out how to complete the `testAPISetup()` method.

Comment: Your controller (and its tests) does way too much. The test for your controller shouldn't test anything about how the API (or what it returns) works. You should just test that the controller calls the right API (using a fake implementation). From there, write separate tests which ensure that the API works properly.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I was trying to use the amount of data returned as a means of testing whether the right API is called. No other variables are setup that would allow me to distinguish between the two responses. Are you suggesting just testing the APIs individually with `URLSession` and forget about the "modes"? Because "You should just test that the controller calls the right API" this is exactly the part that I am stuck at!

Comment: Ah, I see what's tripping you up. No, don't use the results to identify which of the two Network APIs is being called (that doesn't work in the general case, what if you had a dependency that didn't return a result?). [Extract the interface](https://refactoring.guru/extract-interface) of the network clients (I guess in swift you might call it "extract protocol"), inject your network client as a dependency of your VC, and then your test code can use a mock implementation of the protocol, which detects which method was called

Comment: Mhm I was reading on dependency injection to figure out a way but didn't consider setting it up as a protocol and kept thinking i'll have to pass the entire APIManager as an argument. I think i saw something [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/960290-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial#toc-anchor-009) as the `URLSessionMock` class that they use. You can add it as an answer and i'll mark it correct later!

Comment: "i'll have to pass the entire APIManager as an argument." VCs are a bit different from "normal" objects because of their two stage initialization, they're usually allocated and minimally initialized by the system/Storyboard, and then later further "initialized" from `viewDidLoad` and friends to configure your non-view related properties. So you would use something similar to setting injection rather than constructor injection. You would either inject the dependencies via segue, or have default values (which your unit tests could over-write)

Comment: "I think i saw something here as the URLSessionMock class that they use" The `URLSessionMock` would be good for testing the network APIs, but you should still inject them for testing the VC

Comment: Ahhh i just figured out why Dependency Injection is done. Since the app is running while testing, to keep different "environments" for main app run and testing. I unfortunately am using a static session manager so unless i want to change method definitions extensively, I won't be able to do this.

Comment: You can dependency inject a static (shared) object. It isn't as easy but you can do it.

Comment: @matt Mhm interesting. One thing though, since the app is launched while executing test cases. Suppose API-1 is being called via the static `AlamofireSessionManager` in the normal app flow. And i inject (from the test case) into the static variable currently calling the API. Won't that break other functionality since the variable is static?

Comment: @Rikh You just discovered first hand why references to global/static members makes testing difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

What I had for networking:

```
class NetworkingManager{
   static var alamoFireManager = Session.default

   static func POST(...., completion : ()->()) {
       sendRequest(....., completion : completion)
   }

   private static func sendRequest(...., completion : ()->()) {
       let request = alamoFireManager.request(.....)
       request.responseJSON{

           completion()
       }
   }
}

class APIManager{

    static func firstNetworkCall(completion : ()->()){
        NetworkingManager.POST(..., completion : completion)
    }
}
```

I had to change the above and removed all mentions of static and singletons. I decided to go ahead with using class inheritance. I tried to avoid it and use protocols but it frankly was quite easier to use classes!

```
class NetworkingManager{

    private (set) var sessionManager: Session

    init(config : URLSessionConfiguration = .default){

        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 8.0
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 8.0

        self.sessionManager = Session(configuration: config)
    }

    func request(...) {
         //hit alamofire
    }
}

class APIManager : NetworkingManager{

    override init(config: URLSessionConfiguration = .default) {
        super.init(config: config)
    }
    
    //other methods
    ...
}

class Controller{

    private let apiManager : APIManager
    init(manager : APIManager = APIManager()){
        self.apiManager = manager
    }
}
```

And in my test class:

```
override func setUpWithError() throws {

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    try super.setUpWithError()

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
    apiManager = APIManager(config : config)
    controller = Controller(manager : apiManager)
}

func testApiCalled() throws{

    controller.fetchNecessaryInfo()
    //had to add one second delay as alamofire adds the request on another queue. Wasn't able to put it on main queue.
    sleep(1)
    let promise = expectation(description: "Check request called")
    apiManager.sessionManager.session.getAllTasks { (taskArray) in

       if taskArray.count > 1{
           XCTFail("Multiple requests when there should be only one")
       }
            
       if let task = taskArray.first, let request = task.currentRequest{
           if let string = request.url?.absoluteString{
               XCTAssert(...)
           }else{
               XCTFail("Incorrect URL")
           }
       }else{
            XCTFail("Somehow no task exists. So this is an error")
       }

       promise.fulfill()
    }

    wait(for: [promise], timeout: 1.0)
}
```

I couldn't figure out any other way without having to instantiate an object for APIManager, so had to refactor!